# Excel VBA - LDAP Active Directory request with string concatenation

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ldap, string-concatenation

I am trying to lookup contact attributes from our companies Active Directory for a tool I'm writing in Excel 2016. The program should be able to perform database lookups when the user provides either an email address or the full name (`FIRSTNAME LASTNAME`) - whatever they wish to.

This works fine for email addresses and other attributes that are syntactically the same in the database as provided by the user. Unfortunately, the database does not store the full name in the format I need, which is `FIRSTNAME LASTNAME`

So I figured i have to tell the request to also return matches for the attributes `givenname` and `sn` because those constitute the desired full name.

In order to do that i tried the following ways of concatenating the attributes 'givenname' and 'sn'. Neither of them worked:

1. in the SQL's `WHERE` clause I added:

   ```
   ' OR givenname & " " & sn = '" & Trim(rng.Text) & "'
   (see code snippet below)
   ```
2. In the SQL's `SELECT` section, I tested several ways of creating an alias:

   ```
   * ([givenname] || [sn]) As myfullname
   * ([givenname] + [sn]) As myfullname
   * ([givenname] & [sn]) As myfullname
   * and all of the above without square brackets and round brackets
   ```

It seems like the SQL used in the LDAP requests is not fully supported. Because I cannot even create aliases. I also cannot use square brackets or functions such as `CONCAT()` in the SQL command.

Every time I tried one of the ways I got a vba error:

> At least one error occurred

(Translated from German to English)

In other implementations of SQL (not in VBA) this `givenname & " " & sn` works perfectly fine.

**Question**: How can I perform a request that checks my `SearchString` against a concatenation of the attributes `givenname` (firstname) and `sn` (lastname) with a space between them?

```vb
' Connect to active directory
Set objDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
SearchString = "Max Mustermann"

' Contact lookup using SQL-query
objCommand.CommandText = _
    "SELECT givenname, sn, mail, telephoneNumber, mobile, mailNickName, c, l, postalCode, department, company, streetAddress " & _
    "FROM 'LDAP://" & objDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & "' " & _
    "WHERE objectCategory='person' AND (mail = '" & SearchString t & "' OR givenname & sn = '" & SearchString & "')"
Set objRecordset = objCommand.Execute

If Not objRecordset.EOF Then
' Further processing which is not relevant to the question
' ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I finally solved it in way that I was hoping I could avoid. It is certainly not conventional nor is it efficient, but it solves the problem. I wrote a function that would convert the `SearchString` into the format which the database supports.

If anyone out there has a better approach on this, feel free to post it.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the code from the new function?